# Are there any tools for writing a Python code by its TensorFlow Graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

TensorFlow Graphs includes information similar to UML diagrams.

There are special tools (for example "Rational Rose" etc.) for automatic design of application templates for the program by the UML diagrams - computer-aided software engineering (CASE).

Are there CASE-tools for automatic design of application templates on Python for TensorFlow Graphs. Thus, can we build Python code by its tf.graph instead of build a tf.graph by its Python code?

Comment: There is something like that, although not for Python, but for C++. [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla) is an infrastructure for linear algebra acceleration and, among other things, it can do [ahead-of-time compilation](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tfcompile), which essentially takes a graph and converts it into C++. The goal of the tool is to obtain a lighter executable with fewer dependencies, and maybe a bit faster, but not to produce readable code for human edition.

Comment: I believe this is off topic. See: [help/on-topic].